# Mongodb How to start 2 instances mongodb on same server with different IP address and port number

Tags: mongodb

I have netapp mounted as /mongodb and with two different ip addresses. A server have two nodes.  How does Mongodb knows which instance to run.
In configuration setup.  I have two database and each database on each node IP (Multiple instances on same server).

```
Server A
node1: 192.168.6.7
node2: 192.168.6.8
```

Configuration file: mongoDB-01.conf setting parameters

```
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/mongodb/db/mongoDB-01
  journal:
     enabled: true

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
path: /var/mongodb/logs/log-01.log

#Network interfaces
net:
   port:25017
   bindip:192.168.6.7,127.0.0.1
```

Configuration file: mongoDB-02.conf setting parameters

```
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/mongodb/db/mongoDB-02
  journal:
    enabled: true

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
path: /var/mongodb/logs/log-02.log

#Network interfaces
net:
   port:27017
   bindip:192.168.6.8,127.0.0.1
```

Fail to start one of instances.  Do I need adding Ip addresses to Linux IPTable and allowing open port 25017 ?  Thanks in Advance.

```
mongod --config mongoDB-01.conf &  # successful
mongod --config mongoDB-02.conf & # fail to run
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 27009
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 100
```

Comment: Hello. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question. I suggest that you take a look to [MongoDB documentation about Replication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/).

Comment: adding more detail in config.  I have two instances on same server but each instance have it owns IP address and different port number.